# Issue pdf file upload to google docs using java?

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Am trying to upload a pdf file to Google Docs/Drive,
For that am using the following code...

```
int MAX_CONCURRENT_UPLOADS = 10;
int PROGRESS_UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
int DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 10485760;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_CONCURRENT_UPLOADS);
File file = new File(filePath);
String mimeType=DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();
String contentType=DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();
MediaFileSource mediaFile = new MediaFileSource(file, contentType);
URL createUploadUrl = new URL("https://drive.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full");
FileUploadProgressListener listener = new FileUploadProgressListener();
ResumableGDataFileUploader uploader=new ResumableGDataFileUploader(createUploadUrl,mediaFile,service, DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE, executor, listener, PROGRESS_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```

But FileUploadProgressListener showing error,  It is a google api or a class...?

Please help what am wrong to upload a pdf file....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried changing "https://drive.google.com/feeds..." to "https://docs.google.com/feeds..." ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google's older API. Try the new Google Drive API

**Reference :**

https://developers.google.com/drive/

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/drive/cmdline/DriveSample.java?repo=samples&r=08555cd2a27be66dc97505e15c60853f47d84b5a